# Text-Center on Div not Centering the Text? (Twitter Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on the John's Hopkins HTML/CSS and Javascript course on Coursera coding the David Chu's China Bistro using Bootstrap 3.6 (outdated, I know). I came across a problem where the copyright line ended up underneath the third column ([my site screensho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEayl.jpg)) rather than centered at the bottom of the footer ([official site screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i75lU.jpg)). Here is the code for that footer section:

```
<footer class="panel-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section id="hours" class="col-sm-4">
                <span>Hours:</span><br>
                Sun-Thurs: 11:15am-10:00pm<br>
                Fri: 11:15am - 2:30pm<br>
                Saturday collapsed<hr class="visible-xs">
            </section>
            <section id="address" class="col-sm-4">
                <span>Address:</span><br>
                7105 Resterstown Road<br>
                Baltimore, MD 21215
                <p>* Delivery area within 3-4 miles, with minimum order of 
                    $20 plus $3 charge for all deliveries.</p>
                <hr class="visible-xs">
            </section>
            <section id="testimonials" class="col-sm-4">
                <p>"The best Chinese restaurant I've been to! And that's saying
                    a lot, since I've been to many!"</p>
                <p>"Amazing food! Great service! Couldn't ask for more! I'll be
                    back again and again!"</p>
            </section>
            <div class="text-center">&copy; Copyright David Chu's China Bistro 2016</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</footer>
```

Now I understand that it isn't centered because the `div` with the copyright symbol should not be inside the `div` with `class="row"`, but regardless I don't understand why the div is underneath the third column. All of the sections as per Bootstrap should be floated meaning that they are taken out of normal document flow. However, the copyright statement is not floated, so shouldn't that take up the entire width and be centered in the middle of the page? Sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner at HTML/CSS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just to move it up one level outside and I think it will be solved.

```html
<footer class="panel-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <section id="hours" class="col-sm-4">
                <span>Hours:</span><br>
                Sun-Thurs: 11:15am-10:00pm<br>
                Fri: 11:15am - 2:30pm<br>
                Saturday collapsed<hr class="visible-xs">
            </section>
            <section id="address" class="col-sm-4">
                <span>Address:</span><br>
                7105 Resterstown Road<br>
                Baltimore, MD 21215
                <p>* Delivery area within 3-4 miles, with minimum order of 
                    $20 plus $3 charge for all deliveries.</p>
                <hr class="visible-xs">
            </section>
            <section id="testimonials" class="col-sm-4">
                <p>"The best Chinese restaurant I've been to! And that's saying
                    a lot, since I've been to many!"</p>
                <p>"Amazing food! Great service! Couldn't ask for more! I'll be
                    back again and again!"</p>
            </section>
            
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">&copy; Copyright David Chu's China Bistro 2016</div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

If issue still exists, try to use `p` tag for copyright instead of `div`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got that I can fix the problem by moving it up one level, I'm just trying to understand why it's not centered in the page but is rather under the third column when the div is in its original position?

Comment: I would say because the container is "row". Also if someone answer solved your problem, consider to accept https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers